# Generate a pom.xml from the .iml in IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml

I want to Mavenize an existing Java project in Intellij for Git. I've created the pom.xml and the target/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF. In the project Settings all the Modules are visible and I've used Intellij to add all the Artifacts; and it's now able to generate a .jar that works.

However the dependencies are only added in the .iml file, not in the pom.xml. If I open pom.xml and hit cmd+N it only shows me 1 option (mysql-connector-java) and instead of the 20 or so dependencies I have. How do I add my dependencies to my pom.xml?

These are the dependencies in the .iml file that I want to add to the pom:

```
<libelement value="jar://$MODULE_DIR$/lib/log4j-api-2.7.jar!/" />
<libelement value="jar://$MODULE_DIR$/lib/log4j-core-2.7.jar!/" />
<libelement value="jar://$MODULE_DIR$/lib/bluezzz-utils.jar!/" />
<libelement value="jar://$MODULE_DIR$/lib/htmlunit-2.19-OSGi.jar!/" />
<libelement value="jar://$MODULE_DIR$/lib/bpjtk-v3.0.6.0.jar!/" />
<libelement value="jar://$MODULE_DIR$/lib/json-simple-1.1.1.jar!/" />
<libelement value="jar://$MODULE_DIR$/lib/jsoup-1.9.2.jar!/" />
<libelement value="jar://$MODULE_DIR$/lib/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar!/" />
<libelement value="jar://$MODULE_DIR$/lib/junit-4.12.jar!/" />
<libelement value="jar://$MODULE_DIR$/lib/itsm-modules/itsm-maximo-esls2.jar!/" />
<libelement value="jar://$MODULE_DIR$/lib/itsm-modules/itsm-maximo-esls4.jar!/" />
<libelement value="jar://$MODULE_DIR$/lib/itsm-modules/itsm-maximo-gr.jar!/" />
<libelement value="jar://$MODULE_DIR$/lib/itsm-modules/itsm-servicenow-mhas.jar!/" />
<libelement value="jar://$MODULE_DIR$/lib/itsm-modules/itsm-maximo-ess3.jar!/" />
<libelement value="jar://$MODULE_DIR$/lib/itsm-modules/itsm-maximo-ess7.jar!/" />
<libelement value="jar://$MODULE_DIR$/lib/itsm-modules/itsm-maximo-ess8.jar!/" />
<libelement value="jar://$MODULE_DIR$/lib/bluezzz-commons.jar!/" />
<libelement value="jar://$MODULE_DIR$/lib/itsm-modules/itsm-maximo-jll.jar!/" />
<libelement value="jar://$MODULE_DIR$/lib/commons-lang.jar!/" />
<libelement value="jar://$MODULE_DIR$/lib/mywatson.jar!/" />
<libelement value="jar://$MODULE_DIR$/lib/mywatson1.jar!/" />
```

Comment: You have to write an pom file ...correctly put the source code and tests into the appropriate locations ...? Furthermore you should read the docs about dependencies for maven how it works...

Answer (score 0):

I have decided to go another direction and just add all the .jar files to my repository. I didn't realize this was an option, and it completely solves my dependencies problem.

Comment: So no, it actually didn't solve anything. Because Intellij has no idea where those packages are. If I go to Project settings > Modules > Dependencies I don't see any of the packages there. How do I add them?